# Unable to select a row of ListView using White Framework

Tags: listview, white-framework

I am working on WinForms based application. The window has a control which shows is a ControlType.List in VisualUIAVerify. I am able to fetch the instance of the control by using the Control Type as ListView and the automationId. I am able to get the row as well based on the name of the Row. However, when I try to click on the selected row, it doesn't work. I have tried Click(), RaiseClickEvent(), DoubleClick() and Select() on the row.

Following is the sample piece of code :

```
ListView lstOrderables = CurrentWindow.Get<ListView>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("lstOrderables"));
            foreach(ListViewRow row in lstOrderables.Rows)
            {
                if (String.Compare(row.Name, "Post TR DAT", true) == 0)
                {
                    row.Click();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

What else can be done to address this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve it using SelectedItemPattern in the following way:

```
ListView lstOrderables = automationControl.ControlOfType<ListView>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("lstOrderables"));
        foreach(ListViewRow row in lstOrderables.Rows)
        {
            if (String.Compare(row.Name, "ABC", true) == 0)
            {
                SelectionItemPattern pattern = (SelectionItemPattern)(BasePattern)row.AutomationElement.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern);
                pattern.Select();
                break;
            }
        }
```

This would selected the instance of the row with the name as ABC.

Comment: This solution works, but it's necessary to explain that you need to add a reference to  `UIAutomationClient` and `UIAutomationTypes` assemblies and also 
`using System.Windows.Automation;` on the top of the code